# Notepad++ replace a hrefs attributes with plain text

Tags: notepad++

```
<a href="https://acousticguitarlessonsonline.net/acoustic-guitar-playing" rel="nofollow">increase your creativity, motivation, and inspiration to play guitar.</a>
```

This one works for me "]*>([^<]+)" it keep the text untouched but if i want to keep urls with .png or .jpg and none of the rest a href code what should i do ?

this : `<a href="https://www.acousticguitarlessonsonline.net/images/Article-Images/Slide-Guitar-Riff-1.png" rel="nofollow">Slide Guitar Lick 1</a>`

to : https://www.acousticguitarlessonsonline.net/images/Article-Images/Slide-Guitar-Riff-1.png

this : `<a href="https://www.acousticguitarlessonsonline.net/images/Article-Images/Slide-Guitar-Riff-1.jpg" rel="nofollow">Slide Guitar Lick 1</a>`

to : https://www.acousticguitarlessonsonline.net/images/Article-Images/Slide-Guitar-Riff-1.jpg

Comment: You should use `` to wrap your code. This will make your post easier to read.

Comment: thanks , i just fix it .

Comment: Tell me if I'm right, you want to keep only href attribute from all hanchors `<a...>...</a>`

Comment: i want to remove every a href attribute and keep the link for all jpg and png images (i dont want to delete the url of the images only the a hrefs attribute). but keep all the other a hrefs attributes.